# CImg Compilation Error: t_normal not in global namespace

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, libraries, cimg

I'm currently working on a class assignment that requires the use of the CImg library. To be clear, the assignment is not linking the library into the program; The class is using it access the pixel data for later use in the heart of the assignment.

I'm working in Xcode (OS X 10.10). CImg (2.2.2) is installed from homebrew, and I've managed to navigate the weird way Xcode deals with search paths (added the header to the section), and have successfully-ish included CImg.

my full code is as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#define cimg_display 0        //I don't need X11 at all
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
// insert code here...
std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
return 0;
}
```

However, I get 17 Compile-time errors from CImg.h, which are very unusual, and all of the form:

"No member named 't_normal' in the global namespace; did you mean simply 't_normal'?"

Thinking I might have received a bad download, I have attempted to redownload CImg, with no luck. I have also gotten to this same point with non-homebrew versions of CImg.

To verify the download, I also compiled the examples from the command line and they ran perfectly.

Is there a problem with CImg that I'm not aware of, a problem with Xcode that I'm not aware of, or is there something fundamental that I'm missing (definitely an option, my C-style programming is a little rusty) ?

halp pls.

Comment: I have no issues with your code on gcc 7.2.0 on Linux. Compiles fine. I got the CImage from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dtschump/CImg/master/CImg.h

Comment: Good to know I'm not going crazy. My working theory is Xcode is garbage - all my problems disappeared my I starting using a makefile and Vim. Inelegant, but it works.

Comment: I think what works is always more elegant than what doesn't... :-)

Comment: Try updating Xcode to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs fine if you do this:

Create a new Xcode project, with:

- type = *"Command Line Tool"*
- language = "C++"

Then go to *"Build Settings"* and add the path to the directory containing `CImg.h` to your *"User Header Search Paths"*

[image]

Comment: I'm give you the answer because you took the time to post and attach a photo. I had put the include path into that exact field  you've highlighted and had no joy. Thanks for taking the time to comment though : )